# What is the series of the function 3 / ( 1- x^4)

Tags: calculus, functions, summation

I know that $f(x) = \frac{1}{ 1-x }  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$. We can find that $g(x) = \frac{1}{ 1-x^4 } = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (x^4)^n  =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{4n}$. Does the sum converge? what is the convergence radius?

Comment: You have posted two other such questions in the last week: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931712/convergence-of-the-series-from-one-to-infinite-quotient and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931619/how-to-dertermine-this-series-convergence. Please try to keep the grammatical mistakes to a minimum, and format your equations with LaTeX. If you want people to make an effort in their answers, then the same will be expected of you.

Answer (score 0):

The series $ 1+t+t^2+\cdots$ has radius of convergence $1$, so converges if $|t|\lt 1$ and diverges if $|t|\gt 1$. Thus our series $1+x^4+x^8+\cdots$ converges if $x^4\lt 1$, and diverges if $x^4\gt 1$. So we have convergence if $|x|\lt 1$, divergence if $|x|\gt 1$.

**Remark:** Your sums should start at $n=0$, not at $n=1$. And $g(x)=3+3x^4+3x^8+ 3x^{12}+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (3)(x^{4n})$.

Comment: thank you so much sorry about my questions. I don't know really how to speak english well. Have a good nigth

Comment: You are welcome. Don't worry about the English, it will improve. English was not my first language. Nor my second. Nor my third.